# What is the cleanest way to call a command on each new chapter?

Tags: chapters, koma-script, acronyms

I'm using KOMA-Script and a mix of `\chapter` and `\addchap` commands. I would like to have `\glsresetall` called for every chapter as I want my acronyms redefined once per chapter.

What is the cleanest way using either pure LaTeX or a KOMA-Script specific method to have `\glsresetall` called at the beginning of each new chapter?

Ideally the solution should work with the above chapter commands as well as `\chapter*`.

Comment: You mean `\addchap` instead of `\addchapter`, right?

Comment: Oh, and: welcome to TeX.sx! :)

Comment: Yes, I do mean `\addchap`. Oops. Thank you. :)

Comment: But ideally the solution should also work with `\chapter*`. Should maybe have worded the question differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `\addchap` calls `\@schapter`, which is also called by `\chapter*`, one can think to patch both `\@chapter` and `\@schapter`. With the help of `etoolbox` it's quite easy:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\glsresetall}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\glsresetall}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!